# Swift lambda gets inserted into end of argument list

Tags: swift

With Swift 3.1

```
func foo() {
    { () ->  Void in 
    print("oh, nice, now this works too!!!")
    }()
}
foo()
```

works... but

```
func foo() {
    print("Hi!")
    { () ->  Void in 
    print("oh, nice, now this works too!!!")
    }()
}
foo()
```

Will cause

```
ERROR at line 2, col 2: cannot invoke 'print' with an argument list
of type '(String, () -> Void)'
```

That can be fixed inserting semicolon after print

```
print("Hi!");
```

or parenthesis around the lambda definition. However, what I'm interested in is what is the root cause of the behaviour from the Swift compiler perspective?

Comment: It's ambiguous with trailing closure syntax (pretty sure there's a dupe for this somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, you need to separate the print call from the lambda block.

First case:

```
func foo() { () -> () }
```

No problem you can do whatever you want in your closure

Second case:

The compiler thinks you're telling the print statement to execute your closure after it ended.

So you need to separate with semicolon your print("hi") statement or wrap the lambda block to be explicit.

Comment: Noticed that also let stament for example let x = 100 will cause errors if you switch that with print statement, you have to use semicolon there too http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59f0a727c76f6f18f038f747

Comment: Same problem.
You'll get a crash/error on every function that doesn't need a completion block of type () -> ().

You're telling the compiler to executes your lambda block when initializer finishes its job like
    init(value: Int, completion block: () -> ()) {
    self.value = value
    completionBlock()
}

But in your case, it's 2 separated statements.

I hope it's clear enough :)

Comment: If you want to do something like

let x = 100 { print("hi") }

do

var x = 100 {
 didSet {
       print("Hi :)")
    }
}

Comment: oh, that's cool, like func foo() {
 var x = 100 { 
  didSet { 
   print(x) 
  } 
 }
 x = 123456
}  -> so it's the Computed property syntax then

Comment: Yep.

func foo() { var x = 100 { didSet {print(x) } } print(x); x = 10; x= 12 }

will print (100) then 10, then 12.

You also have a willSet operator that you can execute BEFORE setting the variable.
and didSet is executed AFTER setting the variable.

Hope it helps you the way you wanted to.